# Does Vim need to be compiled with Python 3.4.1 to run files through Python 3.4.1 with ":!python file_name?"

Tags: python, vim

When I use this command in Vim

```
:python import sys; print(sys.version)
```

I get:

```
2.7.6 (default, Aug  8 2014, 11:00:32)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)]
```

I'm writing python programs in the Vim editor and want to use the command

```
:!python file_name
```

to run my programs through a python 3.4.1 console. When I type

```
:!python
```

I get a prompt with the correct version of python that I want to use:

```
Python 3.4.1 |Anaconda 2.0.1 (x86_64)| (default, May 19 2014, 13:05:46) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

How can I verify if this is also the version of python that Vim is using when I run a program with

```
:!python file_name
```

If it does run my programs with the correct version (3.4.1) of python, then what does it mean that Vim has been compiled with an earlier version? More importantly, how can I tell Vim what version of python to use to interpret my programs, in case I need to change versions in the future?

Comment: ``:!`` is only a command launcher. It will use the ``python`` command provided by your env.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `:python` yes, for `:!python` no. Also note that python 2 and python 3 are two different incompatible languages, and you can enable one or the other or both to use with `:python` command at VIM compile time.

From vim `:help python` page:

```
The Python 2.x interface is available only when Vim was compiled with the
|+python| feature.
The Python 3 interface is available only when Vim was compiled with the
|+python3| feature.
Both can be available at the same time, but read |python-2-and-3|.
```

So, when you use `:python` it will use the version vim was built with. However, the syntax `:!commandname` will use the usual shell command search rules to execute `commandname`,hence `:!python` depends on which version you have installed.

Answer (score 1):

If your Vim compiled with both versions of python `+python +python3` you can launch internal python with commands `:python` for python2 and `:python3` for python3. But if you launch one of them you can't use other untill restart Vim.